# Strategy for converting 5,000 onclick() pop-up windows to modals

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have getting on for 5,000 different instances of HTML like this...

```
<p class="ltprg">
        <a href="thumbs.php?img=img3/pr600901.jpg&amp;alt=01_September_1960_Events_Programme"
        title="View programme image in new window" onclick="newpop(this.href,'rel','740','520'); return false;"><img
        src="img3/prgcvr16z.jpg" width="90" height="119" alt="" title="01 September 1960 Programme"
        /><br />
        <span class="xtr xbr">01 Sept</span><br />
        Programme</a></p>
```

Don't shout at me, I've been working on this site (in tables, originally) since 2004 and after a hiatus of a few years I've only just recently updated to HTML5 from XHTML Strict, so every page validated, and hopefully still does.

There were a few ambitions attached to this existing approach in that I could place the image in the new window as a background to prevent theft or direct linking. At least the latter stopped as soon as I introduced this method. Now where my understanding fails is that with the pop-up I can create a new DOM simply to display the picture, but that can't happen with a modal. Some of my pages can have up to 40 instances of this code, all unique, in that they will carry images of daily programmes or meal menu covers and content.

Obviously, if I can semi-automate the process of changing my existing code with Regex, that's going to save a mountain of work. Every link has both an image thumbnail of the menu / programme cover and text to describe its destination along with a remote window graphic, all for accessibility reasons which, as a guy with gammy hands, I'd want to preserve and not convert to buttons.

So at present, the main DOM gets a JS script ready to accept the link target, its content, caption and window size, then reacts accordingly on any given click. The new DOM (created by thumbs.php) has its own CSS and close buttons showing the picture as a CSS background image and the caption in a box. With Google Chrome being prevalent now, the window dimensions are presently a mangled mess :/

So, my questions boil down to how to build the modal instances.

(1) Do I simply load one with a PHP include / require towards the end of my HTML?

(2) If so, how do I parse the info for the content?

(3) Can I preserve image / text links instead of using buttons?

At this point, I'm still trying to get my head around the process of how the HTML can be built into the main DOM "on the fly", so it's as my title, I'm still looking at what my strategy should be, rather than code. For example, can I make any use of the existing "thumbs.php" and the newpop() calls with different code?

My fear is that I end up with tons of new code on the main page, which, with over 1,000 pages, I want to avoid. I'm also hoping to avoid having to load many large images on a page load (something I'd not know / recognise I was doing) and also to get the image dimensions direct and influence the CSS to size the modal accordingly.

If you'd like to see the current code in action please visit...[Caronia September 1960 page](https://www.caronia2.info/m196009.php)

Thanks for your interest :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this should be as difficult as you think. Here's an [example](https://codepen.io/shel/pen/EqVdBr) of how you might do this using the html you provided. Whatever php you're using to generate that html, you would just use to generate the below instead.

```
<p class="ltprg">
  <a title="View programme image in new window" onclick="showModal('img3/prgcvr16z.jpg', '01 September 1960 Programme')"><img
src="https://www.caronia2.info/img3/prgcvr16z.jpg" width="90" height="119" alt="" title="01 September 1960 Programme"
/><br />
<span class="xtr xbr">01 Sept</span><br />
Programme</a></p>
```

Comment: Oh wow, your reply went way beyond my expections! I had only wanted to try and understand the "flow" of how modals work as an alternative. In some ways you have overtaken me, because I also have many text transcripts of images that I load into a pop-up - some pages have as many as 15 or more, so I haven't quite got my head around how to deal with those; then there's the slideshows...

There are some questions about your code that I haven't been able to resolve for myself. 

The modal doesn't want to close if a click occurs outside.

Comment: Nice, your changes look great. Not sure what isn't working for you? I did have to clear my browser cache. I updated the code pen with two blocks of JS that should close the modal on an outside click. I should note, this uses [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/) which does have some with its own optional JS but since it looks like you're not using external JS libraries, I just some quick open/close functions from scratch.

Comment: As for your other media you want to load in (text/slideshow), I'm not sure what those look like but I don't know why you couldn't use the same concept. I suppose a last ditch option could be to load the original popup url in an `iframe`. For the image hotlinking issue, I think that would better be handled server-side - [this](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644230/prevent-hotlinking-with-a-htaccess-file) is one option, which should stop most of it.

Comment: The only real question that arises is that pictures that require a horizontal scroll distort within the modal, where it works okay on verticals. Clicking on the ship picture here [link](https://www.caronia2.info/wotsnew.php#update) will demonstrate. The picture meant to appear in the modal is deliberately arranged horizontally, contrary to the vertical in the thumbnail. Adjusting the CSS has defeated me...

Comment: I have encountered a very serious accessibility issue in that without the href address in the links, keyboard access to the images no longer happens. Help, as a disabled person myself I cannot continue with this situation, so I hope there's a simple solution.

Comment: As the sole purpose of the site is to share these artefact images with allcomers, I'm in a serious hole here! It looks like the only solution is to add IDs to each onclick call and add an href to that ID. However, to do this manually through every file will take forever, with a very high error risk. The way to secure individual IDs would be to assign the file's line number, but I don't know of a software that can extract line numbers into Regex - does anyone here know, please?

Comment: Adding `href="#"` to the `a` tag should fix the accessibility issue.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it reloaded the page, or sent it to the top --- was too quick to see which --- either way that's too disconcerting. I have worked out an Ultraedit script to give each call an id, and an href to that id. It means doing each file manually, but I've already reached the letter D, perhaps a few hours more work yet. The progress made thus far is worth it.